# email preferences in codeigniter doesn't works

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my email sending code

function send_letter()

```
{
    $config['mailtype'] = 'text or html';

    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $description =  $this->input->post('description',true);

    $subject =  $this->input->post('subject',true);

    $this->load->model('newsletter_model');

    $this->data['mail_list'] = $this->newsletter_model->getmaillist();

    foreach($this->data['mail_list'] as $val)

    {
        $this->email->from('dfdf1@gmail.com', 'Imageinit');

        $this->email->subject($subject);

        $this->email->message($description);

        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        $this->email->to($val['emailid']);

        $this->email->send();
    }  

    $newdata=array('success'=>1);

    $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);

    $this->index();
}
```

Email sends successfully..but when i send html data mail also contains html data

eg..if i sent data in bold tag .it appears bold tag.doesn't makes the text bold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the config mailtype to html. If you want to send as html then use only **html**. The default mailtype is **text**.

```
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
```

[Email Library config in codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html)